# Can't figure out how to finish a Unix C project

Tags: c, unix, filesystems, system-calls

We are having trouble onf finishing our code for a class prjoect.

In this project, we have to:

- Ask the user for a command
- Create a child process
- The parent receive the command and forward it to the child (+ option and settings)
- The child execute it and then send it back to the parent

Here is what we've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* creation of a variable for the exec */
    char chemin[5] = "/bin/";
    char *cmd[argc - 1];
    int i = 0;
    int fils;
    int mainPipe[2];

    /* Creation of the pipe */
    if (pipe(mainPipe) == -1) {
        printf("pipe failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Creation of the child process */
    fils = fork();
    if (fils < 0) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (fils == 0) {
        /* Child Process */
        /* We redirect the exit to the pipe*/
        dup2(mainPipe[1], 1);

        /* Formulation of the exec */
        for (i = 0; i <= argc - 1; i++) {
            cmd[i] = argv[i + 1];
        }
        strcat(chemin, argv[1]);
        execv(chemin, cmd);
    } else {
        /* Parent process */
        char *buffer[BUFSIZ];

        /* Reception of the command */
        /* We redirect to the pipe */
        dup2(mainPipe[0],0);    
        /* We read the entry in the pipe and put it in the buffer */
        /* Display of the Buffer */
        while (read(mainPipe[0], buffer, BUFSIZ) != 0) {
            write(1, buffer, BUFSIZ);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have left many file descriptors open.  In general, the model is `close(mainPipe[0]); dup2(mainPipe[1], 1); close(mainPipe[1])`

Comment: This `while (read(mainPipe[0], buffer, BUFSIZ) != 0) {
            write(1, buffer, BUFSIZ);
            break;
        }` is wrong.  You should record the size received from `read()` and only write that many bytes with `write()`.  And why a loop with an unconditional break on the first (only) iteration?  That's normally written as an `if` statement.  If you're reading responses from the client, you need to handle bigger responses — some commands can generate multiple megabytes of information in response to a small request.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: *`char chemin[5] = "/bin/";`* How many characters does it take to store that `NUL`-terminated string? (Hint: it's **not** 5)

Comment: How many chars will chemin be after `strcat(chemin, argv[1]);` (Hint I don't know).